# Keeping Count Inside 2 Constructors

Tags: java, constructor, counter, jgrasp

Im doing a program for class. We have to have 2 constructors. How do I keep count in both of them?

For Example: If my test program has 5 different people created with the 2 constructors, how would I be able to return the number of people created?

Inside both of my constructors I have count++ but all it does it return 1.

```
   public Archer(String first, String middle, String last)
   {
      name = first + " " + middle + " " + last;
      count++;
   }

   public Archer(String first, String last)
   {
      name = first + " " + last;
      count++;
   }
```

I've tried to create another instance variable and have that set to equal count but when I did that it returned 0.

Comment: thank you everybody who answered, I didnt even think to make it static

Answer (score 0):

Your `count` variable must be a class-scoped variable for the count of instances to work.

In order to do so, just declare it as `static` in your class, and keep incrementing it as you do in your constructors.

For instance:

```
public class Archer {

  static int count;

  // TODO the rest of the code, and possibly a public getter for the count property
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the count of people inside the class, you need to make the count static.

In a more real scenario, you would rather keep a list of the people and return the count of that, but that depends on your assignment :-)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you have defined your `count`.

If you have defined it as instance variable then result `count = 1` is a correct result, since `count++` will be executed for each object creation and `count` will be bound by the object you have just created. if you would want to know how many times an object was created define `count` variable as `static`